# ACL-based security in an MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-mvc-4

Do you have or know of an example that uses ACL-based security in an MVC app?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This question will most likely get closed as this isn't a site for asking for example or tutorials.  This site is designed around solving actual language programming questions.  I'd suggest reading the [Frequently Asked Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 0):

I don't specifically know of an example, but MVC is naturally very conducive to ACL.  Assign an ACL (or two or three, etc.) to a model.  The ACL can be constructed statically or dynamically depending on your needs.  Store the ACL in a safe place (such as a secure database).  Have the model provide methods to the view that allow it to display itself nicely based on the ACL.  Have the model provide methods to the controller that allow it to be queried for permissions and supply credentials as needed to the model.  Do not allow other modules of the app to access the ACL besides the model.  This preserves the sanctity of MVC.
I recommend considering a role-based ACL instead of user-based, to allow for better scalability in the future in case your app needs it.